# Full-screen videocall interface with iOS14

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, callkit, videocall

with iOS14 CallKit shows a compact call interface.
But in my app, I would like to keep the call with the usual full-screen interface.
Is there a way to set the option programmatically?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no apple public API to do that. Even apple's FaceTime app uses the new CallKit UI.